# Lua 5.1 equivalent of lua_setgcthreshold

Tags: lua, garbage-collection

After updating my lua version from `5.0` to `5.1` 
I get an `lua_setgcthreshold was not declared in this scope`

With `lua 5.0` all work fine.

In lua 5.0  `lua_setgcthreshold` is declared like this :

```
LUA_API void  lua_setgcthreshold (lua_State *L, int newthreshold);
```

But in 5.1 i can't find an equivalent for this.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: I think you just get to read the [Garbage Collection](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.10) section of the lua 5.1 manual and pick new values for the 5.1 gc as it has changed.

Comment: Aniway thanks for comments. I will check lua_gb documentation.

Comment: @Ramy - Lua 5.1 GC is good enough on its default settings.  Only embedded systems may require GC tuning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your situation, the Lua function collectgarbage may be of use to you. See: http://luatut.com/collectgarbage.html